# Save Email after login with ldap

Tags: wordpress, ldap

I am using simple ldap login plugin to login into wordpress from active directory. But after successful login the username field is ok but email field is empty in wordpress users table.

How can i make email saved in the database using this plugin.

The link to plugin is:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-ldap-login/

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after i entered the Base DN in plugin settings to DC=domain,DC=suffix, previously it was empty.